# Создать несколько точек через Классы в opengl и с++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Учим opengl, умею рисовать точку через glutDisplayFunc(), функции Draw где я указываю точку. Но нужно создать точку как класс, и по нажатию на область рисовать эту точку + старые точки должны оставаться нарисованные! 
Вот что есть :

```
    void Initialize()
{
    //Выбрать фоновый (очищающий) цвет
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    //Установить проекцию
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

void Draw()
{
    //Очищаем экран glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Отрисовка квадрата 
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); //Выбираем белый цвет
    glBegin(GL_POINT);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
void timer(int = 0) {
    Draw();
    glutTimerFunc(10,timer, 0);

}
//Войти в главный цикл
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);       //Указываем размер окна
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);   //Позиция окна
    glutCreateWindow("Polygon");        //Имя окна
    Initialize();                       //Вызов функции Initialize
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);  
    timer();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В чем тут собственно вопрос? Immediate mode устарел много лет назад.

Comment: Как это сделать ? что бы точка была в классе ,и по нажатию она нарисовалась. В классе потому что нужно таким образом сделать несколько точек.

Comment: Сделать класс с точкой, сделать метод для рисования этих точек. В чем затруднение?

Comment: Может вам и просто , но я не могу даже примера найти. По скольку я могу сделать класс с точкой, знаю метод для рисования  glutDisplayFunc() и обновления, но я могу туда задать уже готовую точку и потом менять у нее размеры , а вот как добавить в этот метод еще одну точку ? или изначально нужно в методе выделить точки но не отрисовывать их ?

Comment: Ну а в чем затруднение-то? рисуйте вторую так же как и первую...

Comment: Ну если так все просто , покажите как сделать . Лично я не могу понять. Потому что старые точки будут удаляться с новым методом рисовки в другой точке !

Comment: А вам необходимо каждый раз рисовать все предыдущие точки тоже. Содержимое предыдущего кадра теряется. Как продвинутый вариант, можно инкрементально рисовать в текстуру и потом копировать ее содержимое в кадр.